# Moving a wordpress site without passwords or access

Tags: wordpress, migration

I am looking after a site where I have no access from the previous web designer. I have gained access to the domain name, and now want to move the site to my server.

So far I have been able to copy the site using some software I found, and I have the files locally on my computer.

How do I keep the existing site but gain access so that I can update the site?

Will all the links and SEO be disturbed, if I just transfer all files to my server?

Comment: I guess you also have access to the database. You can create a new user via e.g. phpMyAdmin. You may refer to [How can I add a user through SQL?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167389/how-can-i-add-a-user-through-sql).

Comment: You have all files and folders (`wp-content`, `wp-admin`, `wp-includes`) and the database dump?

Comment: i only have access to the domain name and its name servers where i point them to where ever i want.                                                                               All the files i have were downloaded  from the existing site. i dont have access i just copied everything from whats live now. i used some software i found where you enter the url and its save the entire site for off line use so you end up with all the files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to directly copy the site if you don't have access to the server. What you can do is replicate the site. In other words, copy paste all text and images down from the old site. It sounds like you have already done that. Then you set up a fresh WordPress installation on a new server, install the same theme and plugins as you had on the old server and then copy paste in all text and images that you saved previously. Then you can register your site with for example Google Search Console and via that keep track of which URLs that are now returning 404 and set up redirects or new pages for those URLs.